# How to add menu option in TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an android application with tabbed activity. I want a three dot menu option to appear to the right of the tabs. How can I do that?
I want menu option with TabLayout just the one shown in the screenshot.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can add the menu as a tab, just like all the other tabs. Then when it gets selected you inflate meno options.

Comment: @Hashir Sarwar, I, too, was facing the same issue and I was able to solve the problem. If you provided the code for your `onCreate` method in your `Activity`, as well as the XML for your `Activity`, I could easily tell you what to change and what to add to your `Fragment`.

Comment: The `Toolbar` is `ViewGroup` add the `TabLayout` inside and then configure the toolbar menu

Answer (score 1):

Activity layout:

```
...
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabTextColor="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
...
```

Activity class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.my_toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean { ... }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean { ... }
}
```

Result:

[image]

To place the TabLayout below the application name and menu, like:

[image]

You can do this:

```
...
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
    
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabTextColor="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating a menu, create a new resource directory called "menu" and create a menu resource file called "main_menu.xml".Inside that you can create the **items** that you want in the menu. Then you can use [onCreateOptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus) to inflate menu in your .java file.
After that use [onOptionsItemSelected](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) to do some task when the user selects one of the options in the menu.